# Matching string between nth occurrence of character in python with RegEx

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm working with files in a tar.gz file which contains txt files and trying to extract the filename of a the related `TarInfo` object whose `member.name` property looks like this:

```
aclImdb/test/neg/1026_2.txt
aclImdb/test/neg/1027_5.txt
...
aclImdb/test/neg/1030_4.txt
```

I've written the following code which prints the string `test/neg/1268_2`

```
regex = '\/((?:[^/]*/).*?)\.'
with tarfile.open("C:\\Users\\Orestis\\Desktop\\aclImdb_v1.tar.gz") as archive:
    for member in archive.getmembers():
         if member.isreg():
         m = re.findall(regex, member.name)
         print(m)
```

How should I modify the regex to extract only the `1268_2` part of the filenames? Effectively I want to extract the string after the 3rd occurrence of `"/"` and before the 1st occurrence of `"."`.

Comment: `\d+_\d+(?=\.\w+$)` or `\w+(?=\.\w+$)` will do.

Comment: You could probably even do this without regex by doing something like `str_list = in.split('/')[3]` and then `out = ''.join(str_list)` (this will grab EVERYTHING after the third "/").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hardcode this:

```
.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/(.*?)\.
```

More elegant is something along the lines of this:

```
(.*?\/){3}(.*?)\.
```

You can simply change the 3 to suit your pattern. (Note that the group you'll want is $2)